# Touchegg at Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, multi touch not working

Tags: gnome, 14.04, multi-touch, trackpad, touchegg

I've installed touchegg via `sudo apt-get install touchegg`, and also touchegg-gce.

And I am using Apple Magic Trackpad.

My problem is three (or four, five) touch is not responded, and my cursor stop responding. But one and two finger works fine.

Is there ways for me to debug (find out reason)?

I've search around Internet but still confused.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like something crash...
I reconnect trackpad if it is not responded, and it works fine, but still not be able to use multi-touch

Comment: What does the `-gce` package do? I don't seem to have it

Comment: It's an GUI to access touchegg.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by replacing my bluetooth stick.

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323725/apple-magic-mouse-on-ubuntu-13-04-how-can-i-prevent-crashing-one-3-touch-poin).

My comment to the question itself names the exact chipset that was responsible for the misbehaving in my case.

Comment: http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K43SJ/specifications/ - 
"Built-in Bluetooth™ V2.1+EDR" This is my notebook, maybe I should buy a bluetooth stick?

Comment: The specs don't mention the chipset, only its capabilities. Perhaps you can borrow a stick from a friend before to see if it solves your issue. 
You can verify it's the chipset named in my comment by executing `lsusb` from terminal. Your built-in bluetooth should be connected by usb internally. If it's the Cambridge one you don't need to try your friends bluetooth dongle.